# PlaylistItems do not get video by id=cGGaQ4pMbnU, but this video is in the playlist

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

PlayList screen
[image]

---

Request POSTMAN example
[image]

---

**PlayListId**=UUlatNLsHQYQ00TCT3Nfse6w

---

**VideoId**=cGGaQ4pMbnU

---

Why don't I get it? And if I send a request through another account, I get this video, but I need to send a request on behalf of the channel owner.

Authorization goes through Oauth2 Client. 3 days ago (December 13th), I stopped receiving this video via API. It is when I send a request through the channel owner that I do not get video, and if I send it through another account (not the channel owner), I get video.